# Regarding UNIX Variable Date Format

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk, ksh

I have a date value stored in a Unix KornShell (ksh) script variable:

```
VALUE="2010_09_23"
```

I want to change it to "23-Sep-2010" and store it in VALUE1. How can i do it?

```
VALUE1="23-Sep-2010"
```

Comment: You should look into using the tr command, then you can pipe its output into sed.

Comment: You say you're using `ksh` (korn shell) but all the error messages you are pasting in comments are from `bash` - so which are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Ksh has a built-in date formatting capability through the `printf` builtin. The documentation isn't clear about how the argument should be formatted; the following works in my ksh 93s+:

```
VALUE1=$(printf "%(%02d-%b-%Y)T\n" "${VALUE//_/-}")
```

Comment: VALUE1=$(printf "%(%02d-%b-%Y)T\n" "${VALUE//_/-}")
-bash: printf: `(': invalid format character

Comment: @Arav: Your question specifically targeted ksh, and so did my answer. Bash doesn't have any corresponding feature. If you have neither ksh nor better-than-POSIX date, I think your best option is to do it manually (hard-coding month names).

Comment: could be he just doesn't have ksh version 93

Comment: @glenn: Could be (the feature was introduced in ksh 93h, released in 1999), except that no ksh would not complain with `bash: … invalid format character`.

Answer (score 2):

Using portable `awk` and a hardcoded list of month names. The `substr` calls work around a tricky issue is the interpretation of the numbers '08' and '09' in some `awk` implementations: Are they the decimal numbers '8' and '9' or invalid octal numbers?

```
echo "$VALUE" | awk -F'_' '
    BEGIN {
        OFS="-"
        split("Jan_Feb_Mar_Apr_May_Jun_Jul_Aug_Sep_Oct_Nov_Dec", m)
    }
    {
        $2 = 10 * substr($2, 1, 1) + substr($2, 2, 1)
        print $3, m[$2], $1
    }'
```

Answer (score 0):

This command does what you want on OSX:

```
VALUE1=$(date -j -f %Y_%m_%d +%d-%b-%Y "$VALUE")
```

If you are using a different Unix variant, the combination of options to `date` that you require may be different.  The `%`-notation is well standardized (see `man strftime`) but the capabilities of the `date` command are not.

GNU coreutils `date` (what you get on Linux, and which may also be hiding somewhere on your "SunOS" system (I doubt you *actually* mean "SunOS", Sun Microsystems hasn't called its Unix variant that for about fifteen years, but even so, the stuff in `/usr/bin` is still incredibly obsolete junk) -- look in `/usr/local` and all subdirectories of `/opt` -- can also do this but you have to preprocess the input:

```
VALUE1=$(date -d $(echo $VALUE | tr _ -) +%d-%b-%Y)
```

This *may* also work, depending on exactly which shell you have:

```
VALUE1=$(date -d ${VALUE//_/-} +%d-%b-%Y)
```

Comment: Using Sunos & korn shell.   Do i need to change it?

Comment: date: illegal option -- j
date: illegal option -- f

Comment: Augh, SunOS.  You are up Ancient, Nonstandard Tools Creek (even if by "SunOS" you actually mean "Solaris", alas).  fahd's Perl approach is probably your best bet.  If you can find the GNU coreutils somewhere on your system, that version of `date` might be persuaded to do the job, but its `-d` option has a hardwired parser that doesn't understand "2010_09_23", so you'd have to preprocess it (see my edited answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
VALUE="2010_09_23"
VALUE1="$( gawk -v date="$VALUE" 'BEGIN {
    gsub(/_/, " ", date)
    print strftime("%d-%b-%Y", mktime(date " 00 00 00"))
}')"
```

Comment: VALUE1="$( gawk -v date="$VALUE" 'BEGIN {
>     gsub(/_/, " ", date)
>     print strftime("%d-%b-%Y", mktime(date " 00 00 00"))
> }')"
-bash: gawk: command not found

Comment: Unless you can get your sysadmin to install it, I'd go with @schot's or @fahd's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

```
echo 2010_09_23 |  perl '-MPOSIX qw(strftime)'  -le'
    @dt = split /_/,<STDIN>;
    print strftime( "%d-%b-%Y",0,0,0,$dt[2],$dt[1]-1,$dt[0]-1900);
  '
```

Output:

```
23-Sep-2010
```